# "Bad Request: no files uploaded" error While trying to upload a image file with HttpRequest from java client

Tags: java, httprequest, java-client

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {            
try {
     HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
     HttpRequest postRequest = (HttpRequest) HttpRequest.newBuilder()
     .uri(new URI("url to upload file and fetch info "))
     .setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +tokenKey)
     .setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
    .POST(BodyPublishers.ofFile(Paths.get("\\SpringProject\\ImageProcessing\\src\\image.jpg")))
                .build();
                          
     HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(postRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
     System.out.println(response.body());
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

with the above code i am trying to upload a image file and fetch back the details related to that image. But i am getting the below error message from the response body. Please help me to sort out this problem.

```
{
    "result": "FAILED",
    "data": {
        "error_code": 400004,
        "error_message": "Bad Request: no files uploaded"
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the file you want to upload does not exists

Comment: No i am not getting file not found exception

Comment: I am not sure if you get a FNFE in this case. As I know `Paths.get` doesn't thow this exception. I would log out the value of  `Paths.get("\\SpringProject\\ImageProcessing\\src\\image.jpg")` to see if it is the expected one

Comment: I have tried changing the file name(the file that does not exists in the directory) in such case FNFE was caught in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have a problem with the line: `Paths.get("\\SpringProject\\ImageProcessing\\src\\image.jpg")`
The problem is that if your parameter to method `Paths.get` is a valid but non-existent path it will not throw an exception. I.e. path `C:\\test` is valid regardless of whether this path actually exists or not and path `C\#/test\&/` is invalid due to syntactic error. In your case, you provide a relative path. I suggest that you try an absolute path and actually check that it exists before passing it as your parameter.
Also if you are interested I may suggest to try and use a simpler 3d party HTTP client. Here how your code may look like:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.setConnectionUrl("url to upload file and fetch info ");
ResponseHolder<String> responseHolder = null;
try {
    byte[] content = FileUtils.readFileAsByteArray("Absolute path to your file");
    ByteBuffer contentBuff = ByteBuffer.wrap(content);
    Integer length = content.length;
    httpClient.setRequestHeader("content-length", length.toString())
    .setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +tokenKey)
    .setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    responseHolder  = httpClient.sendHttpRequest(HttpClient.HttpMethod.POST, contentBuff);
    String postResponse = responseHolder.getResponseContent();
    System.out.println("Upload (POST) returned String: " + postResponse + "\nresponse: " + responseHolder.getResponseCode() + " " + responseHolder.getResponseMessage());
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println(responseHolder.getResponseCode() + " " + responseHolder.getResponseMessage());
}
```

Note that classes `HttpClient` and `FileUtils` in this code come from Open Source MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. Here is [HttpClint Javadoc](https://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). The library can be obtained from [the Maven Central repository](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or as a jar file from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including Javadoc and source code)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and sharing the code. When i tried with your code it throws ClassNotFoundException at this line of code httpClient.setRequestHeader("content-length", length.toString());

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils at com.mgnt.lifecycle.management.httpclient.HttpClient.setRequestHeader(HttpClient.java:388)
 at Test.pdfToImageConverter(Test.java:41)
 at Test.main(Test.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)

Comment: @Manoj try adding this dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.14.0

Comment: The reason that you got your exception is because you didn't add the dependency for the MgntUtils library. The latest version of it currently is 1.7.0.1. Here is the link where you can see the dependency that you can add: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.7.0.1/jar. Also you can see it here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.7.0.1. And @pochopsp - No he is not missing commons-lang3 it comes as part of MgntUtils

Comment: @Micheal Gantman I am using this library "import com.mgnt.lifecycle.management.httpclient.HttpClient;". Inspite of using it i am getting the class not found exception

Comment: import is not enough - import only says that you want to use this library but it has to be available. You have to either add it as an artifact if you use maven or gradle or any other building framework or add it as a jar on your classpath

Comment: ClassNotFoundException got resolved after adding mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/… jar. But now i get the same error as previous {
    "result": "FAILED",
    "data": {
        "error_code": 400004,
        "error_message": "Bad Request: no files uploaded"
    }
}

Comment: Did you use absolute path to your file that you want to upload?

Comment: Yes, I have used absolute file path.

Comment: This is my absolute path byte[] content = FileUtils.readFileAsByteArray("D:/SpringProject/ImageProcessing/src/sample.pdf");

Comment: So, it is probably some error on the server side. You will need to consult with server side developer and see what exactly the problem is. Perhaps there are some more requirements (such as some other headers) that you need to provide